# Solr: java heap space continually growing

Tags: java, memory, solr

We have a Solr Server (Solr 4.5) with a custom schema and configuration set up for a project under development. Now I have observed, that by running our integration tests the memory usage of the Solr server continually grows. These tests (JUnit) each post a set of 100 randomly generated records to the server, queries around a bit and deletes them.
The deletion policy is set to

```
<deletionPolicy class="solr.SolrDeletionPolicy">
  <str name="maxCommitsToKeep">1</str>
  <str name="maxOptimizedCommitsToKeep">0</str>
</deletionPolicy>
```

Even when the index contains no documents anymore, no memory is freed. Every run of the tests increases the used memory by a certain amount (about 40 M, while the index itself is about 7 k), until the complete server dies with an OutOfMemoryError.

The Solr installation runs on a Tomcat 6.0.35.0, with Java 1.7.0_17 with -Xmx12g. OS is Linux.

How can that be? Where can I tweak the memory handling of Solr?

Comment: do you see any other issues in the logs before the OOM, like too many warming searches on the deck? What are your warmup counts on the different cache types and cache sizes in the solrconfig? These affect the solr's RAM consumption.

Comment: No, there is only one warning in the log (PERFORMANCE WARNING: Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2), no error and no other hints that I had recognized.

Comment: this warning means, that your commits are coming in a quick succession. Each commit will trigger a searcher warmup. But if you have more than one searcher warming up, some of them will waste resources (CPU and RAM) for nothing. The common remedy here is to either set warmup count to 0 (master node) or increase the delay between the commits.

Comment: Well, the memory growth still happens, when I disable warming up (by setting usesColdSearcher to true and removing the warming up queries from the listener events. maxWarmingSearchers is set to 2.

Comment: what's the -Xmx parameter value for the JVM? What's your container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, I have set the cache values and the Xmx too high for the test machine, as a java process uses up more memory than it is assigned to (overhead). With reduced sizes the Solr now runs stable for two days and a lot of unit test runs (which it didn't before).
The test scenario (fill the index with random values and then clean it completely) filled the caches to maximum with records. It seems that removing a record from index not necessarily removes it from the caches...